# Find the greatest $n$ such that $(x-1)^n \mid q(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ — Problem A5 in Putnam Exam 2019

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, contest-math, finite-fields

I am trying to understand the solution to Problem A5 on the 2019 Putnam Exam. The problem and solution are as follows:

[image]

[image]

(Please let me know if my formatting should be different; I am pretty new here.)

I believe I understand the steps up to the result that $n$ is the smallest nonnegative integer such that $(D^n q)(1) \neq 0$. I'm having trouble understanding either of the approaches that follow. In the method given before the remark, I am not sure why $D^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(x-1)^{p-1} = q$. I realize that $$D^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(x-1)^{p-1} \equiv (p-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} x^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (x-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod (x-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$$ by the previously established results, but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

As for the Remark at the bottom, I believe I understand the proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^m$ is congruent to $-1$ or $0 \pmod p$ depending on whether $(p-1) \mid m$. I am not sure how this implies a solution to the problem though. I think that $(D^n q)(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1-n} \frac{(k+n)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (k+n)!}{k!}$ for $n \leq p-1$, but I am not sure where $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^m$ comes in to show that the smallest $n$ for which $(D^n q)(1) \neq 0$ is $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

The webpage I took the problem and solution from is linked here:
https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/

EDIT: I misread $D = x \frac{d}{dx}$ to be $D = \frac{d}{dx}$. My issue is cleared up now.

Comment: To see $D^{(p-1)/2}s=q$ compute it when $s$ is written as $1+x+x^2+...+x^{p-1}$. See how one application of $D$ drops the exponent as a factor to the coefficient, but keeps the exponent as it is. So, when you apply $D$ repeatedly $(p-1)/2$ time, you get the coefficient $k^{(p-1)/2}$ for the term $x^k$.

Comment: The remark is also about checking $(D^ms)(1)$, when you keep $s$ expressed as $1+x+...+x^{p-1}$ and apply the differentiation operator term-wise. The sum in the remark is just $(D^ms)(1)$. The remark is only saying that one can do this computation instead of computing $(D^ms)(1)$ from the formula for $s$ that is $(x-1)^{p-1}$.

Comment: How come the exponent remains the same when $D$ is applied to each term? I must be missing something.

Comment: Oh! $D = x \frac{d}{dx}$, not $D = \frac{d}{dx}$. I misread the entire solution. Thanks.